# buildspec.yml to push to ECR is throwing this error "Command did not exit successfully $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr, buildspec

I am learning on the codepipeline to push the build using CodeBuild to ECR. Below is my buildspec.yml file and the error from the Codebuild logs. Can anyone shed some lights what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**buildspec.yml**

version: 0.2

phases:

pre_build:

```
commands:
  - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.....
  - aws --version
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
  - REPOSITORY_URI=989066xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecs-cicd-nginx
  - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
```

build:

```
commands:
  - echo Build started on `date`
  - echo Building the Docker image...
  - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG .
```

post_build:

```
commands:
  - echo Build completed on `date`
  - echo Pushing the Docker images...
  - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  - echo Writing image definitions file...
  - printf '[{"name":"ecs-cicd-nginx","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
```

artifacts:
files: imagedefinitions.json

**error logs:**
[Container] 2021/07/13 11:13:22 Running command aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.38 Python/3.8.8 Linux/4.14.225-121.362.amzn1.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_ECS_EC2 exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off

[Container] 2021/07/13 11:13:26 Running command $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)

usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

batch-check-layer-availability           | batch-delete-image
batch-get-image                          | complete-layer-upload
create-repository                        | delete-lifecycle-policy
delete-registry-policy                   | delete-repository
delete-repository-policy                 | describe-image-scan-findings
describe-images                          | describe-registry
describe-repositories                    | get-authorization-token
get-download-url-for-layer               | get-lifecycle-policy
get-lifecycle-policy-preview             | get-registry-policy
get-repository-policy                    | initiate-layer-upload
list-images                              | list-tags-for-resource
put-image                                | put-image-scanning-configuration
put-image-tag-mutability                 | put-lifecycle-policy
put-registry-policy                      | put-replication-configuration
set-repository-policy                    | start-image-scan
start-lifecycle-policy-preview           | tag-resource
untag-resource                           | upload-layer-part
get-login-password                       | wait
help

[Container] 2021/07/13 11:13:26 Command did not exit successfully $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1) exit status 252
[Container] 2021/07/13 11:13:26 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/07/13 11:13:26 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1). Reason: exit status 252

Answer (score 10):

For me the problem was I was using **$()** with **get-login-password** command

```
- $(aws ecr get-login-password --region REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin DOCKER_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com)
```

Removing **$()** worked:

```
- aws ecr get-login-password --region REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin DOCKER_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: this worked for me as well. I ran into this issue when changing the AWS CLI version since I had to switch from Amazon Linux 2 to Ubuntu Standard 5 in order to update Node from 12 to 14.

Comment: Worked. Had to add 'https://' before DOCKER_ID

Answer (score 3):

As of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) `get-login` is deprecated in version 2.x of the CLI. It does not exist in the most recent versions.

Use `get-login-password` instead.

Here's an example from the [CodeBuild documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html):
`aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Where do we store the fricken password?????

Comment: why do you want to store it? It's anyhow only valid vor 12h. Just do the above command at the beginning of you build or at the start of your working day

Answer (score 2):

add this permission to role: **"AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess"**

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably the codebuild permission, the role should be like the one below. Pay attention to **ecr:GetAuthorizationToken**, it's the one you are missing. Without this permission you cannot login on ECR.

```
CodeBuildRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - codebuild.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - "sts:AssumeRole"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "PushImageToEcr"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ecr:BatchGetImage
              - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
              - ecr:CompleteLayerUpload
              - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
              - ecr:InitiateLayerUpload
              - ecr:PutImage
              - ecr:UploadLayerPart
              - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
            Resource: "*"
    - PolicyName: "CodeBuildLogsRole"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/*"
    - PolicyName: "GetAndPutArtifacts"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:ListBucket
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt ArtifactBucket.Arn
              - !Sub ${ArtifactBucket.Arn}/*
```