# ECR docker login issues with AWS Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, codebuild

I have created a Build Project with all relevant information. I have also enabled the "Priviledged" in the "Environment" configuration screen.

When starting build in my build log I have the following error:

---

```
[Container] 2023/07/23 07:43:32 Command did not exit successfully $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2) exit status 252
[Container] 2023/07/23 07:43:32 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/07/23 07:43:32 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2). Reason: exit status 252
```

---

Instead of using the command `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)`, I have also tried:

`$(aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reponame)`

Nothing worked!! What am I missing there? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In my `buildspec.yml` file I have the following code:

```
version: 0.2
phases: 
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        docker: 18     
    commands: 
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2&
      - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
  pre_build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.... 
    - aws --version
    # update the following line with your own region
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
    - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
    - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
    - REPOSITORY_URI=123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sample/sampleapp 
  build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Build started on `date` 
    - echo Building the Docker image... 
    # update the following line with the name of your own ECR repository
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
    # update the following line with the URI of your own ECR repository (view the Push Commands in the console)
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG 
  post_build: 
    commands: 
    - echo Build completed on `date` 
    - echo pushing to repo
    # update the following line with the URI of your own ECR repository
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
    - echo Writing image definitions file... 
    #- printf '[{"ImageURI":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imageDetail.json
    - printf '{"ImageURI":"%s"}' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imageDetail.json
artifacts:
  files:
    - imageDetail.json
```

Comment: There should be more error details in the log than just "Error while executing command" Please provide all the relevant error message in your question.

Comment: Yes, it is @MarkB, I have updated the error logs with relevant last 3 lines from the logs.

Comment: Did you look at this question and try all the answers posted there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68361522/buildspec-yml-to-push-to-ecr-is-throwing-this-error-command-did-not-exit-succes

Comment: The link you provided worked @MarkB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @MarkB's suggestion I've found the solution in [this link post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71210177/2206209)

Basically, later I have found that as of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) `get-login` is deprecated in version 2.x of the CLI. It does not exist in the most recent versions.

Besides that there is no need to add the `$()` like [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html).

Finally I changed my statement from:

`$(aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reponame)`

To - removed `$()`

`aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reponame`

Hope this help someone else finding the solution.